# Receiving Error Message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null" when trying to call focus() to an element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element in my DOM where I have attached an ID. I want to call focus on that element after the Page Loads and set it to a css style (border: yellow) to highlight that it's currently focused. This is what I have:

```
//main.html
  <myElement id= 'myEl'>

//main.js
window.setTimeout(function ()  { 
        document.getElementById('#myEl').focus(); 
    }, 0);
```

When I refresh the page I receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Comment: The id value is "myEl", not "#myEl". You don't need the "#" when using `getElementById()`.

Comment: Why are you using raw javascript if you have access to jQuery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That because javascript can't find any element with `id='#myEl'`, remove the extra `#` in :

```
document.getElementById('#myEl').focus(); 
_________________________^
```

Or use jquery selector instead :

```
$('#myEl').focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

Component ID changes in runtime, so use a class rather than ID, will work, like

```
$(".ClassName").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below working code for example reference

**template code**

```
<div class="css-description">description</div>
```

**script code**

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
   $(".css-description").focus();
})
```